# windows random image layer generator

Tags: image, layer

I am working on a personal creative project and need help finding or creating a script that will randomly select 4 images from 4 different folders, stack them and create a series of png composite images as an output. Extra points if the images of each folder can be assigned to a fixed layer (so, for example, images from the "backgrounds" folder will always appear in the back). Note: I don't know how to code.

i am working off windows 10 I tried the answer to this question but it doesn't run on windows

Comment: What do you mean by *"stack"*? Will the output image be as tall as 4 input images? As wide as 4 input images? A 2x2 grid of input images? Or overlaid and blended somehow? Are they partially transparent? Are all images the same size? If not, should they be aligned by their tops? Their centres? Their bottoms?

Comment: As a starter hint, try **ImageMagick**, like this `magick BACKGROUND.PNG IMAGE2.PNG -composite IMAGE3.PNG -composite IMAGE4.PNG -composite RESULT.PNG`.

Comment: so basically i am making Avatars for a game like the portraits and i want to be able to generate lots of them. all of the properties are to proportion i just need to layer them together so the background as layer 1 body as layer 2 shirt as layer 3 facial features as layer 4 however i dont want any of them to duplicate.

Comment: i have 10 of each property in 4 different files and i want them to randomly get put together to put out lots of different combinations having one of each property and i want to be able to make lots at a time. im trying to find a faster way than sitting on photoshop for months adding layers then saving it for 1000s of possible avatars

Comment: so the images are all png and when you load them on photoshop to layer they lineup and blend already i am looking for a way to spam them out

Comment: so i basically want to be able to click generate and the code will spit out randomly layered avatars with one property from each file assigned to each layer

Comment: and then saves them to a designated file or folder

Comment: later on i want to use it for a website where eople can randomly generate their character avatars

Comment: i believe you answered a similar question but that code doesnt work on windows the guy was on osx

Comment: now i wouldnt know how to save it to make it executable either

Comment: id understand a bit of the code

Comment: sort of like when you set up your character for a new sims game and you click randomize but a portrait

Comment: is it possible?

Comment: @MarkSetchell? or is there an app to do it

Comment: could i maybe do it on wix